# Live stream metadata reading in Apple HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: ios, stream, metadata, live, netstream

In the Flash world there is the concept of objects representing a live streaming connection and stream (NetConnection and NetStream).  Though the Flash API these objects can be used to inject text metadata into a live stream (NetStream.send()).  This data can then be listened for at the viewing end in a Flash viewing application with listeners in ActionScript code.  You could pass function calls through a video stream via this and listen for them and execute them on the client end.

Does this concept exist in the Apple HTTP Live Streaming realm?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the metadata is generated to a file by the `id3taggenerator`, and embedded on video using `mediafilesegmenter`, both are included in the [HTTP Live Streaming Tools](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) download. Example:

```
id3taggenerator -o camera1.id3 -text "Dolly camera"
id3taggenerator -o camera2.id3 -text "Tracking camera"
```

There are several kinds of metadata you can embed, including binary objects. Refer to the man page for details. Now we need to reference the generated file from a "meta macro-file". This is a plain text file with the following format:

```
60 id3 camera1.id3
120 id3 camera2.id3
```

The first number is seconds elapsed since the beginning of the video where you want to insert the notification. I don't remember the mediafilesegmenter command exactly, you have to pass the macro file, the index, and the video file at least.

The resulting video contains metadata that is posted by the `MPMoviePlayerController` as notifications. See this page for details: http://jmacmullin.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-meta-data-to-video-in-ios/

Comment: Ahh... Good info. Very much obliged.  So there are native app hooks to do this.  How about purely from a browser?  Can I retreive meta data from HTML5/JS?  Picture commanding that items on the viewer's screen move or change in some way based on commands sent through the video stream.

Comment: I don't think so. It should be in the Safari HTML 5 Audio and Video Guide if existed. Unrelated to HTTP Live Streaming technology, there is a [<track> element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#the-track-element) that is only supported using a JS library named [Captionator](https://github.com/cgiffard/Captionator).